# How to make "Idle" animation like in "Overcooked"?

Tags: animation, bones, weight-painting

I am new here and I wanna try to make Idle animation for my character like in game "Overcooked".

**Example:**

[image]

I try to make skeleton animation like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jp_SqjB0468).

But my Blender give me error.

[image]

[image]

(*I think it's because of my shoulders*).

Anyway, give me, please, some advice and tips, how to make animation correctly for my character? Bone structure? Weights? (*I think error not main qestion?*)

Thanks for attention and help!

P.S. English is not my first language.

P.S.S. Files? [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cfx8e5ha3beuhgs/MagePlayer2.blend?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohdksvkh5d7onqc/MagePlayer2.blend1?dl=0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make it bounces a bit like in your animated gif, you can select your top bone and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Disconnect Bone*. The bone remains the child of the bottom bone but it can move independently. Now you can move it up and down. About the rest of your question, in my opinion it's much too broad for a forum.

[image]